# if (variable == [any item in a collection]) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Let's say I have an array of primitives or a list of objects, doesn't matter, is there a short way of doing this kind of check:

```
if (a_primitive == any_item_in_my_collection) {
    // do something
}
```

or

```
if (an_object_ref.equals(any_item_in_my_collection)) {
    // do something
}
```

without doing this

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (a_primitive == myArray[i]) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have to use arrays? Why not switch to `Collection`-based API?

Then you can use [`Collection.contains(Object o)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

> Returns `true` if this collection contains the specified element. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this collection contains at least one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

Depending on the implementation, this query can be answered in `O(1)` or `O(log N)`.

Comment: 'this query can be answered in `O(1)` or `O(log N)` --- are there any unordered collections this won't apply to? My mind went to arraylists, which I think would be linear, but I don't know if Java actually orders these.

Answer (score 8):

If you want your lookup to be O(1) - you need to mantain the data in an associative array or hashtable.  Otherwise, you're going to have to traverse each element.  The `contains` method is just going to turn around and traverse your List for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;

int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, find_this);
```

(edit: only if array is sorted :) -- see http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_FindInArray.html for details)

Another method I just thought up: to retain your original array, you can do: `List<T> l = Arrays.asList(arr);` where T is the type of the array, then you can do `l.contains(o);`. But this won't work with primitive type arrays, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Check apache commons [ListUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html) and [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) which has contains method.

Comment: ListUtils is a red herring, according to the linked javadoc: there is no `contains` method or equivalent.